# Print multiple rows in some order as different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
/* Note: on update/delete, no action (restriction) is
   the default. (SQL Server & Oracle) */

CREATE TABLE Faculty (
FacNo         CHAR(11)      NOT NULL,
FacFirstName  VARCHAR(30)   NOT NULL,
FacLastName   VARCHAR(30)   NOT NULL,
FacCity       VARCHAR(30)   NOT NULL,
FacState      CHAR(2)       NOT NULL,
FacDept       CHAR(6)       NULL,
FacRank       CHAR(4)       NULL,
FacSalary     DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
FacSupervisor CHAR(11)      NULL,
FacHireDate   DATETIME      NULL,
FacZipCode    CHAR(10)      NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FacultyPK PRIMARY KEY (FacNo), 
CONSTRAINT SupervisorFK FOREIGN KEY (FacSupervisor) REFERENCES Faculty )
go

/* Note: on update cascade for FacSupervisor caused the following error
   in SQL Server 2004:

     Introducing FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT 'SupervisorFK' on table 'Faculty'
     may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION
     or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINTs.
*/

CREATE TABLE Course (
CourseNo      CHAR(6)       NOT NULL,
CrsDesc       VARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL,
CrsUnits      INTEGER       NULL,
CONSTRAINT CoursePK PRIMARY KEY (CourseNo) )
go

CREATE TABLE Offering (
OfferNo       INTEGER       NOT NULL,
CourseNo      CHAR(6)       NOT NULL,
OffTerm       CHAR(6)       NOT NULL,
OffYear       INTEGER       NOT NULL,
OffLocation   VARCHAR(30)   NULL,
OffTime       VARCHAR(10)   NULL,
FacNo         CHAR(11)      NULL,
OffDays       CHAR(4)       NULL,
CONSTRAINT OfferingPK PRIMARY KEY (OfferNo),
CONSTRAINT CourseFK FOREIGN KEY (CourseNo) REFERENCES Course,
CONSTRAINT FacultyFK FOREIGN KEY (FacNo) REFERENCES Faculty )
go

CREATE TABLE Student (
StdNo         CHAR(11)      NOT NULL,
StdFirstName  VARCHAR(30)   NOT NULL,
StdLastName   VARCHAR(30)   NOT NULL,
StdCity       VARCHAR(30)   NOT NULL,
StdState      CHAR(2)       NOT NULL,
StdZip        CHAR(10)      NOT NULL,
StdMajor      CHAR(6)       NULL,
StdClass      CHAR(2)       NULL,
StdGPA        DECIMAL(3,2)  NULL,
CONSTRAINT StudentPk PRIMARY KEY (StdNo) )
go

CREATE TABLE Enrollment (
OfferNo       INTEGER       NOT NULL,
StdNo         CHAR(11)      NOT NULL,
EnrGrade      DECIMAL(3,2)  NULL,
CONSTRAINT EnrollmentPK PRIMARY KEY (OfferNo, StdNo),
CONSTRAINT OfferingFK FOREIGN KEY (OfferNo) REFERENCES Offering
                      ON DELETE CASCADE
                      ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT StudentFK FOREIGN KEY (StdNo) REFERENCES Student
                      ON DELETE CASCADE
                      ON UPDATE CASCADE )
go


INSERT INTO Faculty
VALUES ('543210987','VICTORIA','EMMANUEL','BOTHELL','WA','MS','PROF',120000.00,NULL,'4/15/2005','98011-2242')
go
INSERT INTO Faculty
VALUES ('765432109','NICKI','MACON','BELLEVUE','WA','FIN','PROF',65000.00,NULL,'4/11/2006','98015-9945')
go
INSERT INTO Faculty
VALUES ('654321098','LEONARD','FIBON','SEATTLE','WA','MS','ASSC',70000.00,'543210987','5/1/2003','98121-0094')
go
INSERT INTO Faculty
VALUES ('098765432','LEONARD','VINCE','SEATTLE','WA','MS','ASST',35000.00,'654321098','4/10/2004','98111-9921')
go
INSERT INTO Faculty
VALUES ('876543210','CRISTOPHER','COLAN','SEATTLE','WA','MS','ASST',40000.00,'654321098','3/1/2008','98114-1332')
go
INSERT INTO Faculty
VALUES ('987654321','JULIA','MILLS','SEATTLE','WA','FIN','ASSC',75000.00,'765432109','3/15/2009','98114-9954')
go

INSERT INTO Course
VALUES ('FIN300','FUNDAMENTALS OF FINANCE',4)
go
INSERT INTO Course
VALUES ('FIN450','PRINCIPLES OF INVESTMENTS',4)
go
INSERT INTO Course
VALUES ('FIN480','CORPORATE FINANCE',4)
go
INSERT INTO Course
VALUES ('IS320','FUNDAMENTALS OF BUSINESS PROGRAMMING',4)
go
INSERT INTO Course
VALUES ('IS460','SYSTEMS ANALYSIS',4)
go
INSERT INTO Course
VALUES ('IS470','BUSINESS DATA COMMUNICATIONS',4)
go
INSERT INTO Course
VALUES ('IS480','FUNDAMENTALS OF DATABASE MANAGEMENT',4)
go

INSERT INTO Offering
VALUES (1111,'IS320','SUMMER',2017,'BLM302','10:30:00',NULL,'MW')
go
INSERT INTO Offering
VALUES (1234,'IS320','FALL',2016,'BLM302','10:30:00','098765432','MW')
go
INSERT INTO Offering
VALUES (2222,'IS460','SUMMER',2016,'BLM412','13:30:00',NULL,'TTH')
go
INSERT INTO Offering
VALUES (3333,'IS320','SPRING',2017,'BLM214','8:30:00','098765432','MW')
go
INSERT INTO Offering
VALUES (4321,'IS320','FALL',2016,'BLM214','15:30:00','098765432','TTH')
go
INSERT INTO Offering
VALUES (4444,'IS320','WINTER',2017,'BLM302','15:30:00','543210987','TTH')
go
INSERT INTO Offering
VALUES (5555,'FIN300','WINTER',2017,'BLM207','8:30:00','765432109','MW')
go
INSERT INTO Offering
VALUES (5678,'IS480','WINTER',2017,'BLM302','10:30:00','987654321','MW')
go
INSERT INTO Offering
VALUES (5679,'IS480','SPRING',2017,'BLM412','15:30:00','876543210','TTH')
go
INSERT INTO Offering
VALUES (6666,'FIN450','WINTER',2017,'BLM212','10:30:00','987654321','TTH')
go
INSERT INTO Offering
VALUES (7777,'FIN480','SPRING',2017,'BLM305','13:30:00','765432109','MW')
go
INSERT INTO Offering
VALUES (8888,'IS320','SUMMER',2017,'BLM405','13:30:00','654321098','MW')
go
INSERT INTO Offering
VALUES (9876,'IS460','SPRING',2017,'BLM307','13:30:00','654321098','TTH')
go

INSERT INTO Student
VALUES ('123456789','HOMER','WELLS','SEATTLE','WA','98121-1111','IS','FR',3.00)
go
INSERT INTO Student
VALUES ('124567890','BOB','NORBERT','BOTHELL','WA','98011-2121','FIN','JR',2.70)
go
INSERT INTO Student
VALUES ('234567890','CANDY','KENDALL','TACOMA','WA','99042-3321','ACCT','JR',3.50)
go
INSERT INTO Student
VALUES ('345678901','WALLY','KENDALL','SEATTLE','WA','98123-1141','IS','SR',2.80)
go
INSERT INTO Student
VALUES ('456789012','JOE','ESTRADA','SEATTLE','WA','98121-2333','FIN','SR',3.20)
go
INSERT INTO Student
VALUES ('567890123','MARIAH','DODGE','SEATTLE','WA','98114-0021','IS','JR',3.60)
go
INSERT INTO Student
VALUES ('678901234','TESS','DODGE','REDMOND','WA','98116-2344','ACCT','SO',3.30)
go
INSERT INTO Student
VALUES ('789012345','ROBERTO','MORALES','SEATTLE','WA','98121-2212','FIN','JR',2.50)
go
INSERT INTO Student
VALUES ('876543210','CRISTOPHER','COLAN','SEATTLE','WA','98114-1332','IS','SR',4.00)
go
INSERT INTO Student
VALUES ('890123456','LUKE','BRAZZI','SEATTLE','WA','98116-0021','IS','SR',2.20)
go
INSERT INTO Student
VALUES ('901234567','WILLIAM','PILGRIM','BOTHELL','WA','98113-1885','IS','SO',3.80)
go

INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (1234,'123456789',3.30)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (1234,'234567890',3.50)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (1234,'345678901',3.20)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (1234,'456789012',3.10)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (1234,'567890123',3.80)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (1234,'678901234',3.40)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (4321,'123456789',3.50)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (4321,'124567890',3.20)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (4321,'789012345',3.50)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (4321,'876543210',3.10)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (4321,'890123456',3.40)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (4321,'901234567',3.10)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (5555,'123456789',3.20)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (5555,'124567890',2.70)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (5678,'123456789',3.20)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (5678,'234567890',2.80)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (5678,'345678901',3.30)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (5678,'456789012',3.40)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (5678,'567890123',2.60)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (5679,'123456789',2.00)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (5679,'124567890',3.70)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (5679,'678901234',3.30)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (5679,'789012345',3.80)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (5679,'890123456',2.90)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (5679,'901234567',3.10)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (6666,'234567890',3.10)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (6666,'567890123',3.60)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (7777,'876543210',3.40)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (7777,'890123456',3.70)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (7777,'901234567',3.40)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (9876,'124567890',3.50)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (9876,'234567890',3.20)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (9876,'345678901',3.20)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (9876,'456789012',3.40)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (9876,'567890123',2.60)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (9876,'678901234',3.30)
go
INSERT INTO Enrollment
VALUES (9876,'901234567',4.00)
go
```

Schema for example.

**Get all the faculty numbers (FacNo) and last names (FacLastName) of two different faculty who offered courses in the same offering year (OffYear). There must be no duplicates in the output.**

*Note: For instance, if both P1 Smith and P2 Peters offered courses in 2021, then [P1, Smith, P2, Peters] (or [P2, Peters, P1, Smith], but not both) must be selected. So, the output must look like this:

```
FacNo FacLastName FacNo FacLastName
  ===== =========== ===== ===========
  P1    Smith       P2    Peters     
  ...   ...         ...   ...        
  ===== =========== ===== ===========*
```

I am trying to do something like this and I can't even think where to start? How do I approach this problem?

I tried something like this

```
SELECT f1.FacNo, f1.FacLastName
FROM Offering o1
INNER JOIN Faculty f1 on o1.FacNo = f1.FacNo
INNER JOIN Offering o2 on o1.OffYear = o2.OffYear
```

Comment: Aside... SQL Server 2004? There was no such thing. BizTalk Server 2004 was a thing, but that included SQL Server 2000 SP4. [Error 1785](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-1785-database-engine-error) happens because you can't include cycles in cascading updates and deletes, which includes self-referencing the table in your SupervisorFK foreign key.

Comment: You need to show us your desired results for the provided sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Joining the `Offering` table twice on the `OffYear` correctly gets you the combinations of courses in the same year. Since you want the names of the two faculty members, you also need to join the `Faculty` table twice:

```
    SELECT f1.FacNo, f1.FacLastName, f2.FacNo, f2.FacLastName
      FROM Offering o1 
INNER JOIN Faculty f1 
        on o1.FacNo = f1.FacNo 
INNER JOIN Offering o2
        on o2.OffYear = o1.Offyea
INNER JOIN Faculty f2
        on o2.FacNo = f2.FacNo
```

This will however include exact duplicate rows (e.g. when two faculty members had two courses in the same year), combinations of faculty members with themselves and duplicate combinations of names in reverse order (both [P1, Smith, P2, Peters] and [P2, Peters, P1, Smith]).

To get rid of the exact duplicates, use `SELECT DISTINCT` instead of `SELECT`. The other two problems can be easily fixed with one `WHERE` condition: By limiting results so that the first member's `FacNo` is smaller than the other's, unwanted combinations are filtered out.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT f1.FacNo, f1.FacLastName, f2.FacNo, f2.FacLastName
      FROM Offering o1 
INNER JOIN Faculty f1 
        on o1.FacNo = f1.FacNo 
INNER JOIN Offering o2
        on o2.OffYear = o1.Offyear
INNER JOIN Faculty f2
        on o2.FacNo = f2.FacNo 
WHERE f1.FacNo < f2.FacNo
```

See [this dB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=561efb0ca00bdc8dfca2162aacd0c910).